How to collect doubles from user input and print them using a "pointer" to a "vector"?
It is a code that gets some doubles from the user input, and then prints them.
Input looks like this 1 2 3 4.5 x, where x is an arbitrary non-double to break the first for loop.
However, it segfaults!
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<double> *b;
    for (double i; cin >> i;)
    {
        b->push_back(i);
    }

    for (double j:(*b))
    {
        cout << j << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


Why did you make b a pointer?

@Yksisarvinen Just to practice.

b is a pointer to vector. There is no vector being pointed to. That's why it segfaults. You shouldn't practice using "naked" pointers like this. It's a bad practice carried over from C. Use a plain vector, and drop all the pointer shenanigans.

Think of a pointer like a piece of paper with an address written on it. When you have an address of a house, you can go there, look around, put things inside or take them away, even rebuild the house. But your piece of paper has nothing written on it, you cannot go to a house that doesn't exist and put things inside. You have to build a house (create a vector), then take a piece of paper (pointer) and write down the address of the house 9take address of the vector).

Worse, an uninitialized pointer could point ANYWHERE, including at a perfectly valid house that belongs to someone else. Walking into that house and poking a round is NOT recommended. You are lucky when the program crashes over using an uninitialized pointer because you could just as easily be generating bad results and making bad decisions by reading or writing  the wrong memory.

In the case of a library container like a string or a vector, a huge part of their job is to hide pointers and management of what's being pointed-at from you. It's unusual to see a pointer to one. If you have to pass one by reference, you use a reference. Almost every time you see one being dynamically allocated with new, you're looking at a mistake that'll probably result in one or more bugs. Better to leave the container as an automatic variable and let it do management for you.

It segfaults because the b pointer doesn't point to anything. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer leads to undefined behavior, which may include a segmentation fault.
You could dynamically allocate the vector so that the pointer actually points to valid memory. Remember to explicitly delete it.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    auto b = new std::vector<double>();

    for (double i; std::cin >> i;) {
        b->push_back(i);
    }

    for (double j : *b) {
        std::cout << j << "\n";
    }

    delete b;
    return 0;
}

Or use a smart pointer.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    auto b = std::make_unique<std::vector<double>>();

    for (double i; std::cin >> i;) {
        b->push_back(i);
    }

    for (double j : *b) {
        std::cout << j << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

But your best bet is to drop the pointer entirely and just use a vector.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<double> b;

    for (double i; std::cin >> i;) {
        b.push_back(i);
    }

    for (double j : b) {
        std::cout << j << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

If you're concerned with stack memory usage, don't be. Barring providing your own customer allocator that changes the behavior of std::vector, this container dynamically allocates its storage already.
